# How do I check if a list of lists exists in a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I got a list of lists **b** and I want to check if they exist in list **a** which is also a list of lists.

I'm currently using the following method which is quite time-consuming. Is there a faster way?

```
b  = [[5], [5, 3], [5, 3, 1], [5, 3, 1, 2]] 
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

result = all(elem in b[0] for elem in a[0])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[1] for elem in a[0])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[2] for elem in a[0])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[3] for elem in a[0])
print(result)

result = all(elem in b[0] for elem in a[1])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[1] for elem in a[1])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[2] for elem in a[1])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[3] for elem in a[1])
print(result) 

result = all(elem in b[0] for elem in a[2])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[1] for elem in a[2])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[2] for elem in a[2])
print(result)
result = all(elem in b[3] for elem in a[2])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
>>>True
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
>>>False
```

Comment: Is that the output you want? False, False, False, True, False etc.?

Comment: `[i for i in a if i in b ]`

Comment: Yer sir, I'm going to edit it now

Comment: II don't understand the question. If you want to check if the content of each inner list of `b` is contained in any inner list of `a` then you should have only 4 outputs because there are only 4 inner lists in `b`.

Comment: Additionally: Your code doesn't check what you described. In your code you check if the content of each inner list of `a` is contained in any inner list of `b`. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You do the same thing with a double loop O(n^2):

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(b)):
        print(all(elem in a[i] for elem in b[j]))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(b)):
   if b[i] in a:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```